# can't draw an image using Graphics.DrawImage method from form1_Load event handler .?

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics2d

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(@"F:\face.jpeg");
   Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
        g.DrawImage(b, 20, 30);


    }
}
```

Image doesn't load with the form. 
What is the reason for this? And, how can i do this?

Comment: Well, of course not, the window is not yet visible when the Load event fires.  Use the form's Paint event instead, use e.Graphics.

Answer (score 2):

Because it's not a proper way to draw in WinForms. Move your draw code to `OnPaint()` method like this:

```cs
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, 20, 30);
}
```

Of course it's fine to load the bitmap earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Paint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint.aspx) event... Refer [Form graphics not set when form loads](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2684065/3467213)